# How to switch ubuntu in CUI and GUI mode (for memory saving)?

Tags: gui, vmware, tty

I installed ubuntu 14 desktop version with VMWare Fusion on my mac, as I need to execute some linux binaries on mac. The issue is that ubuntu itself occupies almost 1G bytes of memory with the GUI. I sometimes need to run the GUI programs, but most of the time, I use ubuntu as a server accessed with ssh from mac. So, it's overkill when I assigned only 2G memory for the virtual machine to run ubuntu.

My question is how to switch ubuntu in GUI or CUI (command line user interface, i.e., text mode) mode in this case to save memory?

I'm not trying to run cui mode at booting time, I just want to switch between gui and text mode.

Comment: Just run it without starting the GUI and use `ssh -X` to forward X apps. or use a light weight GUI such as LXqt (uses 300 mb RAM)